# Snowflake Data Unload to csv files

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While using copy into command to unload data from Snowflake, will data storage cost increase if I don't use any compression and directly bring csv files which accounts to around 500 mb data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output files are not compressed, they will probably consume more space and it may increase the costs.

Depending on Cloud Provider and region, Snowflake storage costs may be different but it's around $40-50 per TB/month. So if the total size is about 500 MB, this will not make a big difference.

Snowflake pricing page: https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/

AWS S3 storage: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/

Comment: Thank your for the response! I am using internal Stage of Snowflake to store the csv files temporarily and once the ETL load is complete, the files are removed from Stage. So, just wanted to understand what difference will be there in cost of data storage.

Comment: I find the best way to get the potential increase in costs of not decompressing the files would be to test.  Test with a subset of files for a month and see how much more it cost than the previous month. If this amount is reasonable to your business needs, then continue using it.  I usually recommend decompression in general of files to save some money on storage, but it might not be a big difference in your use case.  Additionally, here are some docs on how this is calculated: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/credits.html#data-storage-usage